# Thought I understood static classes

Tags: c#, oop, static

Trying to construct a helper class that will return an arraylist, but I'm getting the following error, having to do with the xml document I need to create:

> Util.oDocument': cannot declare instance members in a static class

I think I understand why you wouldn't want to create a new xmldoc object each time this method gets called, but I need that doc in there for the functionality. How should I be approaching this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;

public static class Util
{

    public static ArrayList multipleArtistList(string artistName)
    {
        XmlDocument oDocument = new XmlDocument();

        string uri = "http://api.leoslyrics.com/api_search.php?auth=duane&artist=" + artistName;
        oDocument.Load(uri);

        XmlNodeList results = oDocument.GetElementsByTagName("name");
        ArrayList artistList = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!artistList.Contains(results[i].InnerText))
            {
                artistList.Add(results[i].InnerText);

            }

        }

        return artistList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you /sure/ that oDocument is declared inside the method, or is it a field?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that code.  You should only get that error if the declaration for oDocument was outside of any functions.

Comment: The previous comments seem correct.  Otherwise you wouldn't be able to declare any of the other variables you are using, either.

Comment: Just tried compiling that code in MonoDevelop with no errors. No access to VS at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error here:

```
Util.oDocument: cannot declare instance members in a static class
```

means that you've declared oDocument *outside* of the method.

There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, in fact the error and the code contradict each other.

Make sure that `oDocument` is declared inside the method. If you want to declare it as a field, make sure to give it the `static` modifier, like so:

```
public static class Util
{
    static XmlDocument oDocument;

    /* code */
}
```

Comment: cool, thanks.  tried it again and it was fine.  good to know I was on the right track.